Looking for a movie about street gang violence with the phrase "She cut my face!"
I'm looking for a movie about gang street violence, similar to Defiance, which I saw about 30 years ago.
I remember only one scene. A girl (probably a prostitute) cut the face of one the gang members and he said before killed her "She cut my face! She cut my face!!!".
The gang was probably Mexican or South American, but I am not sure.
Things I am reasonably certain about:

Year of Release: 1970-1984
Country of Origin: USA
Genre: Action, Gang, Crime
Released on: TV, probably also shown in cinemas


Searching for the quote you mentioned, Fort Apache, The Bronx came up, a 1981 American crime drama film.


Police officers face many challenges in the decaying, impoverished, high-crime South Bronx region of New York City. Among these officers are NYPD officers Murphy (Newman) and Corelli (Wahl), who work out of the 41st precinct, nicknamed "Fort Apache" because to those who work there, it feels like an army outpost in foreign territory (an allusion to Fort Apache out of the Old West). The streets are filled with dangerous gangs, criminals, and drug dealers. Unemployment is very high and the neighbourhood is filled with garbage and wrecked buildings. While Murphy is a hard-drinking and lonely divorced father, he has a great camaraderie with Corelli. As well, Murphy's life improves when he meets a young nurse, Isabella, and they start a romantic relationship.

Drawing from the script:

But you don't care... 'cause you're too busy lookin'.
  You goddamn whore!
  Drop that!
  She cut my face!
  - Bitch.
  - Drop it!
  You killed her!
  Oh, shit.
  She's dead.
  Oh, my God, she's dead.
  Shut up! It's your fault for having her here in the first place.

Unfortunately, that script site is missing a lot of details such as what is going on in the scene and who's speaking. The Wikipedia article does note that the officers have issues because so few of them are Puerto Rican, which suggests that the gangs may be from there, which would fit your belief that they might be South American.
The entire film appears on YouTube:



From there, I've found that the "she cut my face" scene happens around 1 hour 21 minutes into the film.
